# How to map unspecified path using Rack::Builder.map?

Tags: ruby, rack

I know I can map a path using:

```
map '/' do
  run app
end
```

But I want to send an error page when it is an unspecified path. Something like:

```
map others do
//...
end
```

I tried to search online about Rack but little info was found.

PS. Please don't ask me to use Sinatra or Rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just have a default app that produces the error message if the request doesn’t match any of the other mappings:

```
map '/one' do
  run app1
end

map '/two' do
  run app2
end

run default_app
```

Alternatively you could have a mapping for `/`, since [“URLMap dispatches in such a way that the longest paths are tried first, since they are most specific”](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/Rack/URLMap.html). (This is actually pretty much equivalent to having a default app like above).

```
map '/one' do
  run app1
end

map '/two' do
  run app2
end

map '/' do
  default_app
end
```